# How does dancing work?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

I've got some nice dance moves for my tiny companions and I'm not quite sure how the whole system works.  Which effects happen when they dance?  Is there any way to make them dance on command?

Comment: I've never been quite sure of this myself :(

Comment: Well, the general idea is to step to the beat.  Depending on the dance, you might step two or three times per beat, or only once every two beats.  The direction and technique of these steps also differs per dance.  At the end, you gain a buff called, "Good with the ladies".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every dance combination will give your companions four possible dances they can perform. Each dance will result in a different effect, such as giving you an Attack Boost, healing you, or boosting your defense. The frequency at which they dance depends on the Mask they're wearing. I'm uncertain if the dance they perform is completely random, but they will only perform a dance when it will be beneficial (i.e. they won't perform a healing dance when your health is full). Certain masks will modify the frequency at which they dance, with some masks resulting in more dancing and others resulting in less.

I am not aware of any way to make your companion dance on command.

Comment: You can make them do the dance "emote" kind of thing, but I, too, am unaware of a way to make them perform specific buff dances.

Comment: Some abilities (i.e. Hunter) encourage dancing more than others. Masks that encourage long-range attacks also keep them from getting knocked out as often, so they'll dance more too.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig: Good point. I've added in a sentence addressing that in my answer.